# Add a String Array to a JList

Tags: java, arrays, swing, jlist, windowbuilder

I'm trying to put my String Array in a JList but nothing happens.
What am I doing wrong?

```
JList<String> list = new JList<String>();
list.setBounds(22, 111, 190, 395);
jpPanel.add(list);

btnTestList.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {

                String [] testArray = {"a","b","c"};
                list.setListData( testArray);
}
        });
```

Comment: If you have problems, please show us a an MCVE: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve . Since it isn't clear what exactly you are trying and what you have tried and not tried.

Comment: @Marcel. Great advice. And a tip: `[mcve]` in a comment auto-expands to [mcve].

Comment: Java GUIs have to work on different OS', screen size, screen resolution etc.  using different PLAFs in different locales.  As such, they are not conducive to pixel perfect layout.  Instead use layout managers, or [combinations of them](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5630271/418556) along with layout padding and borders for [white space](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17874718/418556).

Comment: String array is set to the JList when you press this `btnTestList` (I guess it is a button). Did you press this button?

Comment: of course I pressed it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is Ok, try to look for a bug somewhere else through the code. Here is an example that demonstrate that this part of your code is really workable, may be this will help you to find a mistake.

```
public class NewJPanel extends JFrame {
public NewJPanel() {
    this.setSize(400, 300);
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    Container container = this.getContentPane();
    JPanel jpPanel = new JPanel ();
    container.add(jpPanel);

    GridBagLayout gridBagLayout = new GridBagLayout();
    jpPanel.setLayout(gridBagLayout);

    JButton btnTestList = new JButton("New button");
    jpPanel.add(btnTestList);

    JList<String> list = new JList<String>();
    GridBagConstraints gbc_list = new GridBagConstraints();
    gbc_list.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
    gbc_list.gridx = 0;
    gbc_list.gridy = 1;
    jpPanel.add(list, gbc_list);

    btnTestList.addActionListener(new ActionListener () {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
             String [] testArray = {"a","b","c"};
             list.setListData( testArray);
        }
    });   
}


public static void main(String[] args) {
    NewJPanel jPnl = new NewJPanel ();
    jPnl.setVisible(true);
}
}
```